# ¿como redirigir utilizando php y sweetalert?

Tags: php, mvc, sweetalert2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando esto pero no funciona ¿ quiero que al dar click en el botón ok del `sweetalert` me redirija

Comment: ¿Qué versión de `sweetalert` estas usando?

Comment: es la version 2.1.2

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js

Comment: Daniel bienvenido. Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y agregues tu código como texto en vez de poner una imágen. [Pásate por acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que entiendas de lo que hablo.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la función `.then` que se ejecuta después de que el usuario interactua con el mensaje.

```js
swal({
    title: "Bien!",
    text: "Adelante!",
    type: "success"
}).then(function() {
    window.location = "https://es.stackoverflow.com/";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: no me funciona la probé con php y nada

Comment: Debes de tener algo mal en tu código, puedes compartirlo con nosotros revisa que la consola no te arroje ningún otro error.

Answer (score 0):

Después de `swal(`te falta abrir llaves y cerrar llaves al final, quedando así:

```
echo '<script>
        setTimeout(function() {
        swal({
        title: "¡Genial!",
        text: "Validación exitosa, revise su correo electrónico para ver sus datos de acceso",
        type: "success",
        confirmButtonText: "OK"           
        }, function() {
        window.location = "verificar.php";
        });
        }, 200);
        </script>';
```

> Te recomiendo 200ms que 1000ms por cuestión de tiempo de respuesta, pero es opcional de tu parte.

Comment: no entiendo por que no me funciona y la imagen que  publique  acá si me funciona pero me falta la redirección

Comment: alguna otra idea?

Comment: ¿Te aseguraste que el resultado de la validación sea realmente exitosa? asegúrate que llegue hasta el re direccionamiento, pues si estás seguro que si funciona, puede que el programa no llegue hasta el re direccionamiento.